# How to allow the User to both draw and type in a UITextView in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to make a UITextview drawable since it is a subclass of the drawable UIView. 
When the switch,on the view controller, is on I'm going to disable the drawability and enable the UITextInput and scrollview. When the switch is off user would be able to draw on the entire visible part of the UITextView. 
I don't want to disable the user interaction on the UITextView, which is why I couldn't find any function that disables solely the text input part whereas the on touch is still working. I've also tried the UIImageView drawables but I couldn't make the height dynamic, so that it can increase directly proportional to the height of the UITextView. Which method would you suggest in my case?